# Read a list out of a csv by python DictReader

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

My CSV file looks like this:

```
YY,XX,ZZ
[14, 18, 13, 0],"[7, 7, 9, 9]",[]
```

Now i use dictread as this:

```
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for line in csv_file:
  a=line
```

Now i get:

```
print(a)
>> {'XX': '[7, 7, 9, 9 ]', 'YY': '[14, 18, 13, 0 ]', 'ZZ': '[]'}

print(a["XX"])
>> [7, 7, 9, 9]

b=a["XX"]
print(b[0])
>> [
```

I'd like to read in the elements from my csv as a dictionary but the values should be contained in a list, so i get a 7 instead of a [:

```
print(a)
>> {'XX': '[7, 7, 9, 9 ]', 'YY': '[14, 18, 13, 0 ]', 'ZZ': '[]'}

print(a["XX"])
>> [7, 7, 9, 9]

b=a["XX"]
print(b[0])
>> 7 <----
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there.

You have strings that LOOK like lists, but they are strings. Just filter the string elements in the dict through [ast literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse it back into a Python list:

```
>>> di={'XX': '[7, 7, 9, 9 ]', 'YY': '[14, 18, 13, 0 ]', 'ZZ': '[]'}
>>> import ast
>>> for k in di:
...    di[k]=ast.literal_eval(di[k])
... 
>>> di
{'YY': [14, 18, 13, 0], 'XX': [7, 7, 9, 9], 'ZZ': []}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, especially for the explanations. i tryed it with the str.split() method but this gave bad results. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'r'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

def proc_line(line):
    keys,vals = zip(*line.items())
    return dict(zip(keys,map(ast.literal_eval,vals)) )

for line in map(proc_line,csv_file):
  keys,vals = zip(line.items())
  a=dict(zip(keys,map(ast.literal_eval,vals)) )
```